Using Zapier in Asana to Find Most Common Values of Fields to Show in Portfolio View
I'm currently trying to build a database that allows my company to track freelancers that we work with.
Right now, we have a system designed where each new assignment that a contractor is given is a task, & each of those tasks are added to a project that matches their name. Each of these projects lives in one big portfolio that we call the Creator Database. Because we use the same contractors often, they sometimes perform different roles for us (i.e. sometimes they'll be an editor, & sometimes they'll be a copywriter). Their Roles are determined in a custom, multi-select field that each task associated with them has filled out.
My vision is to have the Creator Database (in portfolio view) display only the most commonly-assigned roles for each project. For example:

Say I've hired Joe Schmoe for 3 assignments. For 2 of them, Joe Schmoe worked as an editor. For 1, Joe Schmoe worked as a copywriter. In the portfolio view, under another custom field entitled "Primary Position, only the role "Editor" would appear for Joe Schmoe, since that is his most common role.

Does anybody have any suggestions on either a) troubleshooting the error that I keep getting, or b) another way to accomplish my goal?
Zapier has allowed me to build a custom task to accomplish this where it will scan all the tasks within a project when a project is added to the portfolio & then change the value of the "Primary Position" field; however, when I try to test it, I keep getting an error message that states that the project I'm testing with does not have a recognized project ID. (The project definitely does exist.)
